# Mistake when calculating modular inverse using Euclid's algorithm

Tags: modular-arithmetic, inverse, euclidean-algorithm

So I've attempted calculating the modular inverse of $3$ modulo $68238256$, but my answer is wrong. I know the answer should be $45492171$, but I keep getting $22746085$. I can see that $68238256 - 22746085 = 45492171$, but I don't know how to get there.

Here is my incorrect attempt:

$d \times 3^{-1} \equiv \pmod{68238256 }$

Using Euclid's algorithm:

$68238256=3 \times 22746085+1$

$3=1 \times 3+0$

Substitute:

$1=68238256-3 \times 22746085$

Therefore,
$d=22746085$

Comment: You want $d\times 3\equiv 1,$ not $d\times 3^{-1}\equiv 1.$ Doesn’t seem to account for your error, though.

Comment: $68283256-22746085=45537171$; is it $68238256$ or $68283256$?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner You're correct it's 68238256. I've fixed the typo in the post. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Okay, I changed my answer accordingly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be $d\equiv\color{red}-22746085\equiv45492171\bmod68238256$

Comment: Oh that makes sense. Can't believe I missed that! Thanks!

Comment: By the way, if $n\equiv1\bmod3$ then $3^{-1}\equiv\dfrac{2n+1}3\bmod n$